# Compute the covariance of $\xi$ and $\min \{\xi,2\}$, where $\xi$ is exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $\xi$ be a random variable exponentially distributed and let $\xi_1=\min \{\xi,2\}$. Calculate $Cov(\xi,\xi_1)$.

I know the problem is easy but I just need somebody to check my work. Here's my solution.

$$
E(\xi\cdot\xi_1)=\int_0^\infty x\cdot\min(x,2)\cdot\lambda\exp(-\lambda x) \,dx=
\int_0^2x^2\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \,dx+2\int_2^\infty x\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \,dx=\int_0^{2\lambda} \lambda^{-2} t^2e^{-t}\,dt +\frac{2}{\lambda}\int_{2\lambda}^{\infty}te^{-t}\,dt=\frac{-e^{-t}(t^2+2t+2)}{\lambda^2}|_{t=0}^{2\lambda}+\frac{-2(1+t)e^{-t}}{\lambda}|_{t=2\lambda}^{\infty}=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}(1-e^{-2\lambda}(\lambda+1)).
$$
Next
$$
E(\xi_1)=\int_0^{\infty}\min(x,2)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\int_0^2 x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx+2\int_2^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx=\lambda^{-1} \int_0^{2 \lambda}te^{-t}\,dt+\int_{2\lambda}^{\infty}2e^{-t}\,dt=\frac{-e^{-t}(1+t)}{\lambda}|_{t=0}^{2\lambda}-2e^{-t}|_{t=2\lambda}^{\infty}=\frac{1-e^{-2\lambda}(1+2\lambda)}{\lambda}+2e^{-2\lambda}=\frac{1-e^{-2\lambda}}{\lambda}.
$$
Hence
$$
Cov(\xi,\xi_1)=E(\xi\cdot\xi_1)-E\xi\cdot E\xi_1=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}(1-e^{-2\lambda}(\lambda+1))-\frac{1-e^{-2\lambda}}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1-e^{-2\lambda}-2\lambda e^{-2\lambda}}{\lambda^2}
$$
Could you please check whether it is correct?

Comment: Something must be wrong, the limit for $\lambda\to0$ is $2$.

Comment: I can't see the mistake in my calculations however it must be somewhere... :-(

Comment: Ooops, no sorry, the covariance tends to the variance, which is $2$. This is correct.

Comment: Yves! Which variance? $Var(\xi)=1/\lambda^2$.

Comment: I'd better move on to another question :(

Comment: For what it's worth, simulation with a million values using $\lambda = 2$ gives cov = .227, which agrees with your result to three places. Also, agreement on .594 using $\lambda = 1$. Of course, that's not the same as my verifying your integrations, but such agreement would be remarkable if your formula is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the integration, and since BruceET checked the result numerically, chances are that it's correct.